# Execute batch of prepared statement in Java Sql taking long time during Last iteration

Tags: java, sql, database, prepared-statement, hana

I'm trying to insert large amount of rows into various tables in database from java application. so basically i have a single connection with which i create multiple Prepare statements. Then i prepare several inserts by setting the variables of prepare statements. Finally i execute every Prepare statement as execute Batch and close the statement.

Problem I'm facing is that, i'm doing an iteration over the above mentioned process.

I have a method writeToDataBase(), which does the above mentioned operations, and this method is called inside a loop. thus the batch insertions are happening many times.(every batch consists of 20 objects). Every time this insertion takes around 5 to 6 seconds to do a batch insertion in one iteration. but in the final iteration it takes a very long time about 40 seconds.

i thought this would be due to the data being written in the last iteration. Thus i also changed the data to make it lightweight but even then the problem persisted. Then i tried disabling the auto-commit and commit it manually. That didn't help either.

i also changed the number of iterations. for example,

In a loop of 20 counts ,20th loop would take a lot of time. so i changed it to run for 5 times. but this time the 5th loop ran longer. basically the last loop takes a long time to execute batch.

to check there is no memory leak, i'm also closing the statements are its execution. But i'm not able to understand why this is happening.

code snippet is provided below.

```
for(ArrayList<DocumentObject> batch : documentBatches){  
   DBWriter.writeToDataBase(batch);  
 }

 public static synchronized boolean writeToDataBase(ArrayList<DocumentObject> batch)       {  
      try {  
    //Prepare Statements for insertion  
      String insertDocumentTableSQL = "INSERT INTO TEST.DOCUMENTS values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";  
      PreparedStatement documentPreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertDocumentTableSQL);  
      String insertSentencesTableSQL = "INSERT INTO TEST.SENTENCES values (?,?,?,?,?,?);";  
      PreparedStatement sentencesPreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertSentencesTableSQL);  
    //Preparing multiple inserts to the prepare statements  
    for(DocumentObject docObj : batch){  
    documentPreparedStatement = prepareInsertsToDocumentsTable(docObj,documentPreparedStatement);           //sets the '?' in the query with actual values and adds it to the batch  
    sentencesPreparedStatement = prepareInsertsToSentencesTable(headlineSRLDocument, sectionId,sentencesPreparedStatement);  
        }  
    //execute the preparestatements  
      connection.setAutoCommit(false);  
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();  
      documentPreparedStatement.executeBatch();  
      sentencesPreparedStatement.executeBatch();  
         connection.commit();  
      documentPreparedStatement.close();  
      sentencesPreparedStatement.close();  
    System.out.println("time taken for Execute Statements: "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start)/1000+" seconds" );  
    return true;  
    }
```

Below is the console output that i had got to track the time taken for every iteration.

> time taken for Execute Statements: 3 seconds
>
> time taken for Execute Statements: 4 seconds
>
> time taken for Execute Statements: 4 seconds
>
> time taken for Execute Statements: 4 seconds
>
> time taken for Execute Statements: 5 seconds
>
> time taken for Execute Statements: 5 seconds
>
> time taken for Execute Statements: 9 seconds
>
> time taken for Execute Statements: 10 seconds
>
> time taken for Execute Statements: 6 seconds
>
> **time taken for Execute Statements: 47 seconds** <------ last iteration taking more time

Comment: Try adding these timing statements around each call to pinpoint which function is taking more time? BTW what database is this?

Comment: is any garbage collection activity happening at this time?

Comment: Hi Sameer , I'm using SAP HANA database. and i have found that .executeBatch() statements are taking more time. but however in other iterations its not consuming so much time. I'm not sure about the garbage collection activity.

Comment: i checked on garbage collection by calling system.gc(). now every iteration took 2 or 3 seconds more. but the last loop took even longer to execute than normal.

Comment: Could you get a DBA to check the transaction commit time at database level? Problem could be at application level (e.g. garbage collection happening) or at database level. If db can confirm what time it received batch transactions, and how much time it took to process them , it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. This was basically happening as the last loop was preparing more statements and adding it to the batch, when compared to other loops.

I checked this , by having a consistent data set where i knew the number of statements which would be prepared for every loop and added to batch. previously the statements were generated and added dynamically and thus i had no clue on the number of statements being executed in a loop. Hence, There is no problem with the preparedStatement.executeBatch()  or the Database as i had presumed.

Thank you for helping me out.